# How to change circle colours in leaflet based on a variable?

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet, r-markdown

For a certain online course, I made a quick interactive map using leaflet in Rmarkdown and published it to Rpubs. The data is about world cities and their population.

I was trying to make colour gradient based on the population size of a city. For example red for Tokyo and green for a city with lesser population (~=1-2). Below is the code I used to generate the published map [here](https://rpubs.com/vermaph/344805):

````
---
title: "Global population concentration"
author: "Piyush Verma"
date: "December 28, 2017"
output: html_document
---


```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=12, fig.height=8)
```


```{r, message=FALSE,warning=FALSE,results='hide', echo=FALSE}
set.seed(2017-12-27)
library("data.table")
cities<-fread("./worldcities.csv")
cities<-cities[cities$pop>0,]
```

```{r, message=FALSE,warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, width = 40, height = 30}
library("leaflet")
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "Red",domain = cities$pop)
cities2<-cbind(cities,col=pal(cities$pop))

my_map <- cities2 %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addCircles(weight = 1, radius = sqrt(cities$pop) * 110) %>% setView(lat = 51.4826, lng = 0.0077, zoom = 2) 
my_map
```
````

I downloaded the data from [here](https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities):

I tried using help from [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/colors.html) but ended up producing error `Error in polygonData/default(data): Dont know how to get path data from object of class numeric`

Any help would be a great help for the future. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to

```
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = c("green", "red"), domain = cities$pop)

my_map <- cities2 %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addCircles(weight = 1, radius = sqrt(cities$pop) * 110, color = ~pal(cities$pop)) %>% 
  setView(lat = 51.4826, lng = 0.0077, zoom = 2)
```

and it works. Needs some fine-tuning though. `colorQuantile` might be better suited.

[image]